# how to abbreviate the acronomy of a column value in datagrid in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

here in my datagrid am having a column as "Type" .In that column the binding values will be 'I' or 'E' and the same will be displayed .here i need to get the column values as "Internal" for 'I' and "External" for 'E'.the below is the code sample for that column

```
 <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Transfer Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a value converter.  This sort of thing is needed a lot so I prefer a general converter than to create a specific one.   Get cut'n'paste the code for "StringToObjectConverter" from this blog: [Yet another blog about IValueConverter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/06/09/yet-another-blog-about-ivalueconverter.aspx).

With this converter in your project in the default namespace (which we by convention map to the local: alias) you can now add an instance to a resource in your UserControl/Page:-

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:StringToObjectConverter x:Key="TypeFieldConverter">
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <sys:String x:Key="I">Internal</sys:String>
                <sys:String x:Key="E">External</sys:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </local:StringToObjectConverter>
    </UserContro.Resources>
```

Note there is also another sys: alias needed

> xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Now you can assign the converter to your binding:-

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Transfer Type" Binding="{Binding Type, Converter=TypeFieldConverter}"  />
```

Comment: I think you have wrongly added the hyper link for the StringToObjectConverter class

Comment: @Prabhakaran: Sorry I pasted in the wrong URL.  I have corrected it now.